# Can't seem to adjust div width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an add content form but the width of the forms container div wont seem to adjust no matter what I try. I've rechecked my CSS inputting in VS code, simply by adding a div container and adjusting everything with the same code, and it works just fine. Am I missing something?

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

input[type=text],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="/images" method="post">
    <label for="gName">Gallery Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="gName" name="gallery[name]" placeholder="Enter Gallery Name">
    <label for="image">Image URL</label>
    <input type="text" id="image" name="gallery[image]" placeholder="Enter Image URL">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="gallery[description]" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused-- you are using Node.JS for this?  Or do you mean JavaScript?  It seems like you are running your code in the browser, and I don't see any JS at all here...

Comment: Sorry I only realized later that my description of what I'm trying to do was a bit confusing. Not sure why I even mentioned JS as it doesn't really apply in this case, still a newbie so all these languages used can get a bit confusing. I do have JS code in other files which works perfectly. This issue is just CSS related, I've created a form within a DIV container, and in a separate CSS file I'm trying to set the width of the container but it doesn't seem to change, the height and every other property works weirdly enough..

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification.  I've taken the liberty of removing references to Node; [you can see the revision here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63681226/revisions).  In case this is a point of confusion for you: NodeJS and JavaScript are not the same thing and you cannot use the terms interchangeably.  JavaScript is a _language_, and is by far the most common scripting language used in the browser.  [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) is a runtime environment _for_ the JavaScript language _outside_ of the browser, for things like tooling and servers.

Answer (score 1):

The brief explanation, is that the input has natural paddings, border-width that adds up to the total height/width of the element.

```
width + padding + border = actual width
```

For debuging purpose, you can set padding and border-width to zero. You will see that it will fit perfectly

```css
input[type=text], textarea {
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Using `box-sizing` will include the padding and the border to the calculation to the actual total size.

```
width = actual width + padding + border
```

```css
input[type=text], textarea {
  box-sizing:border-box
}
```

For more detailed info see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just add inline styling to your form tag, I set your padding to 5%, you can change it to your liking. You can also use width except of padding like `style="width: 30px"` or play around with different pixel values.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

input[type=text],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="/images" method="post" style="padding: 5%">
    <label for="gName">Gallery Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="gName" name="gallery[name]" placeholder="Enter Gallery Name">
    <label for="image">Image URL</label>
    <input type="text" id="image" name="gallery[image]" placeholder="Enter Image URL">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="gallery[description]" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

input[type=text],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="/images" method="post">
    <label for="gName">Gallery Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="gName" name="gallery[name]" placeholder="Enter Gallery Name">
    <label for="image">Image URL</label>
    <input type="text" id="image" name="gallery[image]" placeholder="Enter Image URL">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="gallery[description]" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```